# appcmd.exe set config doesn't check if username or password is invalid and sets it anyways

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, active-directory, iis, windows-server

I'm using winexe from my backend api to run commands on Windows Domain Server.
I want to set IIS App Pool Identity as an Account from Active Directory.
The problem is that while using this command

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools ^
/[name='POOLNAME'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser  ^
/[name='POOLNAME'].processModel.userName:DOMAIN\USER  ^
/[name='POOLNAME'].processModel.password:PASSWORD
```

It runs successfully every time even if the username and password is incorrect. Even the pool gets started with wrong password. However, setting wrong password through GUI fails.

I want to identify when the password or username is being set wrongly.

**PS:** I even tried using `Set-ItemProperty` on powershell and the result was the same.

Comment: Why the double post?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849272/appcmd-exe-set-config-doesnt-check-if-username-or-password-is-invalid-and-sets